# how to map json data from string from s3 to athena?

Tags: json, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have data in this format in s3 
2019-07-02T00:00:00+00:00  web.app.req_res {x:y,y:{p:q}}
how can i create table from only json data in aws athena?